# Automapper performance significantly degrades in multi-threading environment

Tags: .net, multithreading, performance

We use Automapper tool to map complex object in multi-threading environment. 
I decided to measure Automapper performance running this code on my machine with 8-core CPU:

```
    private const int NumberOfThreads = 8;
    Parallel.For(0, 50000, 
              new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = NumberOfThreads }, 
              RunMapping);
```

This code works fine until I increase number of threads to 16 and higher. If I set it to 16 threads (`private const int NumberOfThreads = 16;`) performance starts degrading in time, gradually and slowly from 0.3 sec (average time per mapping) to like 0.5 in the end of mapping all 50000 objects of same complexity. If I set it to 32 threads even worse: from like 0.4 to 2.8 (7 times!) in the end. However, got no issue at all under 8 threads environment: might run for hours with stable execution time, did many attempts to make sure. I tried to declare both transient and singleton mapping service: makes no difference. Other than that, I did not notice any memory leaking on any amount of threads.

I wonder what might be wrong in Automapper design that makes it getting slow with number of threads more than number of CPU cores (I think it might be related). Any guesses are welcomed.

UPDATE: Visual Studio Profiler shows hundreds of threads if I select wide range of data collected and when you go down hierarchy you will see [External Code] taking like 0.02% of cpu time, there just many of such threads and all them collectively takes 93% of cpu. So I do not know how VS Profiler can help me to detect the problem

BTW, if I put running threads on hold it restores performance to initial state, but it starts degrading again with the same amount of threads

Comment: How many cores your machine has?

Comment: I suspect this is because there are some cached plans that require a ConcurrentDictionary to lookup because the cache requires locking. Have you run this under a profiler?

Comment: 8 cores.
@JimmyBogard What kind of profiler? I run Windows Resource Monitor

Comment: If performance is critical, you might want to consider ExpressMapper instead.

Comment: Then please post more complete code. This is just a generic loop. if this loop was broken then all Parallel.For usages in the world were broken.

Comment: @usr it's tird-party tool, I do not have source code, i just run its mapper on some object of complex structure (many nested and nested of nested objects)

Comment: Post the code of RunMapping. You also should run a perf profiler and post a screenshot of the results. Maybe internal contention will be apparent.

Comment: The code is as simple as instantiating `ObjFrom` and  running `Mapper.Map<ObjFrom, ObjTo>();`. There is nothing special in mapping setup as well, it all looks like `Mapper.CreateMap<From, To>()` for root and any nested objects

Comment: I use dottrace from JetBrains which tells me why things are awry.

Answer (score 1):

With 8 cores, you can run 8 threads on hardware simultaneously. Maybe 16 with [hyper threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading).

Anything above that number requires your CPU to use any kind of [scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)) to make it look like they are running in parallel. This will take more time.

Comment: more threads will definitely take more time per thread to do the job, but it does not explain why is this time increasing. It's supposed to be the same job. It's like if you run to calculate fixed math function in 32 threads 50K times, and you may expect it takes approx. equal amount of time for first 100 times and last 100 times, but in fact last 100 calculations run 7 times slower.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, the job you do is CPU-bound. Now, if you split the job in smaller pieces, you add overhead for each split. However, if this allows you to execute the pieces in parallel, the overall time is reduced. Now, if you split this in more pieces than you can execute in parallel (which is the number of CPUs), you only add overhead! Even worse, you add context switches (including cache invalidation) to the overhead, so the required time may well degrade.

Comment: Let's say if I replace the Automapper's mapping by complex math function 32 threads do not show performance degrade, it takes slower to run the function per thread, but it's a stable time.

Comment: Well, in that case you should perhaps add that info to your question. Also, what is the difference between the two code variants? As a third variant, consider using a simple `sleep()` call. Lastly, what does the profiler say where you spend your time?